# Doing some downloading without blocking you app

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm working on my first app that's doing a few different web connections at once.

My first screen is my Menu.

And at the bottom of viewDidLoad of MenuViewController i call a method that gets and parses a .xml file that is located on my webserver.

Also at the bottom of viewDidLoad i do

```
FootballScores = [[FootBallScores alloc] init];
```

and FootballScores makes a connection to a html page which it loads into a string and then parses out data.

Now since both of these are getting called at the bottom of viewDidLoad of the class thats is responsible for the main menu(first screen in the app) it means the app is kinda slow to load.

What is the right way to do the above? Should i remove the 2 pieces of code from my viewDidLoad and replace with maybe

```
dataGetterOne = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.000 target:self  
selector:@selector(xmlParser) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

dataGetterTwo = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.000 target:self  
selector:@selector(htmlParser) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

This would mean that the methods get called later on and the viewDidLoad gets to finish before the i try get the data from the web servers.

Making 2 connections to we bservers a second apart to quick? Can the iphone handle having 2 connections open at once?

I'm really unsure of anything bad/dangerous I am doing in regards to connections.

Many Thanks
-Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also, [I wrote a brief tutorial](http://longweekendmobile.com/2010/10/15/how-to-consume-json-or-xml-web-apis-on-iphone-smoothly/) on writing your own XML/JSON data-parsing app.  I hope it may be helpful in thinking about how to structure such an app.

Comment: Hi Phooze, thats look very interesting. A lot of pointers there for me. Have you hosted the source for the project anywhere? Would like to be able to read it all.

Comment: @Code - not yet :) I get a lot of requests for it, so I SHOULD do it one of these days.  Leave a comment on that site if you have specific questions and I can help.

Comment: Nothing specific yet! Just started coding it following your guide now :) One of the code boxes doesn't seem to be displaying correctly on your site.

Answer (score 3):

Try using [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/). It's easy to use and lets you make asynchronous requests that don't block your app with few lines of code.

Hope this helps,

ender

Comment: +1 You can write your own asynchronous calls but ASIHTTPRequest is much easier, and likely to be better than what you'd write.